# Where am I causing this SIGABRT error when calling PlayerInLobbyMenu?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, sigabrt

Currently getting a SIGABRT crash exception thrown when my player changes teams from red to blue or vice versa in the lobby. The crash occurs inconsistently, but always when player changes teams. PlayerInLobbyMenu is the player itself in the lobby and its label is PlayerInLobby.

NOTE: when I comment the code in PlayerInLobbyMenu the crash does not occur at all.

In the code below I will show what these two objects are and how they are getting called:

```
struct PlayerInLobby: View {
    let player : User
    @EnvironmentObject var lobbyService : LobbyService
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                if player.username == lobbyService.myLobby.host!.username {
                    Image(systemName: "crown.fill")
                }
                Image(systemName: "person")
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(player.username)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Members Stats")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }

                if lobbyService.myLobby.playersReadyList.contains(player) {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .padding(5)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "x.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(5)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

```
struct PlayerInLobbyMenu: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var lobbyService: LobbyService
    @ObservedObject var myUser : MyUser
    let player : User
    @State var playerMemberRow: PlayerInLobby
    @EnvironmentObject var alertBannerService: AlertBannerModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu {
                if myUser.username == lobbyService.myLobby.host!.username && playerMemberRow.player.username != myUser.username{
                    Button("Kick Player", action: {
                        do {
                            try lobbyService.deletePlayer(lobbyId: myUser.lobbyId!, playerUsername: player.username)
                        } catch {
                            alertBannerService.alertMessage = "Could not kick player."
                            alertBannerService.showingNotice = true
                        }
                    })

                }
                Button("View Profile", action: {

                })
            } label: {
                playerMemberRow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how PlayerInLobbyMenu is getting called:

```
struct TeamContainer: View {
    var backgroundColor : Color
    var containerWidth : CGFloat
    var teamColorName : String
    @EnvironmentObject var lobbyService : LobbyService
    @ObservedObject var myUser : MyUser
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("\(teamColorName) Team")
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(backgroundColor)
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    if teamColorName == "Blue" {
                        ForEach(lobbyService.myLobby.blueTeam, id: \.self) { player in
                            PlayerInLobbyMenu(myUser: myUser, player: player, playerMemberRow: PlayerInLobby(player: player))
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(lobbyService.myLobby.redTeam, id: \.self) { player in
                            PlayerInLobbyMenu(myUser: myUser, player: player, playerMemberRow: PlayerInLobby(player: player))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: containerWidth)
        .background(backgroundColor.opacity(0.3))
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

This is the crash report that I get when debugging (not sure if this will be helpful):

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x000000010919ce60 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x000000010937f3c0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 256
    frame #2: 0x00000001091043d8 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 120
    frame #3: 0x0000000131b2b284 AttributeGraph`AG::precondition_failure(char const*, ...) + 188
    frame #4: 0x0000000131b13e54 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::add_input(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int) + 684
    frame #5: 0x0000000131b1485c AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 256
    frame #6: 0x0000000131b2a628 AttributeGraph`AGGraphGetValue + 228
    frame #7: 0x0000000113d29928 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.DynamicBody.updateValue() -> () + 256
    frame #8: 0x0000000113ef7780 SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for implicit closure #2 (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in implicit closure #1 (τ_1_0.Type) -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 () -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafePointer<τ_1_0>) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> in AttributeGraph.Attribute.init<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 == τ_1_0.Value, τ_1_0: AttributeGraph.StatefulRule>(τ_1_0) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> + 28
    frame #9: 0x0000000131b0dd20 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 524
    frame #10: 0x0000000131b0e2cc AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 400
    frame #11: 0x0000000131b148d0 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 372
    frame #12: 0x0000000131b2a628 AttributeGraph`AGGraphGetValue + 228
    frame #13: 0x0000000113f6ddc4 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.AnimatableFrameAttribute.updateValue() -> () + 52
    frame #14: 0x000000011374aec4 SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for generic specialization <SwiftUI.ViewFrame, SwiftUI.AnimatableFrameAttribute> of implicit closure #2 (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in implicit closure #1 (τ_1_0.Type) -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 () -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafePointer<τ_1_0>) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> in AttributeGraph.Attribute.init<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 == τ_1_0.Value, τ_1_0: AttributeGraph.StatefulRule>(τ_1_0) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> + 20
    frame #15: 0x0000000131b0dd20 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 524
    frame #16: 0x0000000131b0e2cc AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 400
    frame #17: 0x0000000131b18e40 AttributeGraph`AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 948
    frame #18: 0x0000000114001410 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.GraphHost.flushTransactions() -> () + 404
    frame #19: 0x0000000114001f68 SwiftUI`closure #1 (SwiftUI.GraphHost) -> () in closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI.GraphHost.asyncTransaction<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: SwiftUI.GraphMutation>(_: SwiftUI.Transaction, mutation: τ_0_0, style: SwiftUI._GraphMutation_Style, mayDeferUpdate: Swift.Bool) -> () + 20
    frame #20: 0x00000001139dd328 SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (SwiftUI.ViewGraph) -> τ_1_0 in SwiftUI.ViewGraphDelegate.updateGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.GraphHost) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 20
    frame #21: 0x0000000113f18f80 SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> τ_1_0 in SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.ViewGraph) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 88
    frame #22: 0x0000000113f14608 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.ViewGraph) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 92
    frame #23: 0x00000001139cd098 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewGraphDelegate.updateGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.GraphHost) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 56
    frame #24: 0x0000000114001f48 SwiftUI`merged closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI.GraphHost.init(data: SwiftUI.GraphHost.Data) -> SwiftUI.GraphHost + 120
    frame #25: 0x0000000113a2fc84 SwiftUI`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out ()) + 20
    frame #26: 0x00000001138211c0 SwiftUI`static __C.NSRunLoop.flushObservers() -> () + 140
    frame #27: 0x000000011382112c SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static __C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> () + 12
    frame #28: 0x000000011381ab88 SwiftUI`function signature specialization <Arg[1] = [Constant Propagated Function : closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static (extension in SwiftUI):__C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> ()]> of reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Swift.Error) to @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out (), @error @owned Swift.Error) + 20
    frame #29: 0x00000001084b8f50 libswiftObjectiveC.dylib`ObjectiveC.autoreleasepool<τ_0_0>(invoking: () throws -> τ_0_0) throws -> τ_0_0 + 56
    frame #30: 0x0000000113821110 SwiftUI`closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static __C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> () + 48
    frame #31: 0x000000011382124c SwiftUI`@objc closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static __C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> () + 52
    frame #32: 0x0000000109cdbf9c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    frame #33: 0x0000000109cd6724 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 556
    frame #34: 0x0000000109cd6c84 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 976
    frame #35: 0x0000000109cd63a8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    frame #36: 0x000000010d0335ec GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
    frame #37: 0x000000010fa0e7ac UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 992
    frame #38: 0x000000010fa132e8 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 112
    frame #39: 0x0000000113f707f4 SwiftUI`closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>>>) -> Swift.Never in SwiftUI.KitRendererCommon(Swift.AnyObject.Type) -> Swift.Never + 160
    frame #40: 0x0000000113f70750 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.runApp<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: SwiftUI.App>(τ_0_0) -> Swift.Never + 164
    frame #41: 0x00000001139c64f4 SwiftUI`static SwiftUI.App.main() -> () + 80
  * frame #42: 0x0000000102ce44b8 Hoops`static HoopsSUIApp.$main(self=Hoops.HoopsSUIApp) at HoopsApp.swift:13:1
    frame #43: 0x0000000102ce4564 Hoops`main at HoopsApp.swift:0
    frame #44: 0x0000000106af1ca0 dyld_sim`start_sim + 20
    frame #45: 0x0000000106bc1088 dyld`start + 516
```

The player changes lobbies by making a call to a realm database (this is done using the lobbyService environment variable) and removing themselves from the current team they are on and adding themselves to the new team here:

```
                        Menu {
                            Menu {
                                Button(action: {
                                    do {
                                        try lobbyService.setTeam(username: myUser.username, lobbyId: lobbyService.myLobby._id, teamChoice: "RED")
                                    } catch {
                                        alertBannerService.alertMessage = "Could not put you on red team"
                                        alertBannerService.showingNotice = true
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Red")
                                })
                                Button(action: {
                                    do {
                                        try lobbyService.setTeam(username: myUser.username, lobbyId: lobbyService.myLobby._id, teamChoice: "BLUE")
                                    } catch {
                                        alertBannerService.alertMessage = "Could not put you on blue team"
                                        alertBannerService.showingNotice = true
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Blue")
                                })
                            } label: {
                                Button(action: {

                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Choose Team")
                                })
                            }

                            Button(action: {
                                do {
                                    if myUser.username == lobbyService.myLobby.host?.username  && lobbyService.myLobby.playerList.count > 1 {
                                        try lobbyService.assignNewHost(lobbyId: lobbyService.myLobby._id, currentHostUsername: myUser.username)
                                    }
                                    try! lobbyService.deletePlayer(lobbyId: lobbyService.myLobby._id, playerUsername: myUser.username)

//                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                                    }

                                    
                                } catch {
                                    alertBannerService.alertMessage = "Cannot leave lobby"
                                    alertBannerService.showingNotice = true
                                }
                                
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Leave lobby")
                            })
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.dotted")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        }
```

Does anything stand out that is causing this crash? Would love to be educated on where  I really messed up. Thanks.

Comment: How do you move a player between teams? How does your player conform to `identifiable`? This `playerMemberRow: PlayerInLobby(player: player)` looks a bit suspicious.  I wouldn't go passing `View`s as a parameter.  Just pass the player and then have `PlayerInLobbyMenu` call `PlayerInLobby`

Comment: @Paulw11 just added more information to the post how the user is getting added to the team etc.

Comment: There is a `try !` - which is a potential source of a crash, but the first thing I would do is change your code so that you pass the player, not a view as per my previous comment

Comment: @Paulw11 Took out the playerMemberRow parameter and inside PlayerInLobbyMenu I inputted the label for the menu as: PlayerInLobby(player: player) and that still produced the same error

Comment: I suspect that the problem is inside your model object, `LobbyService` - You have to be careful with the potential for concurrent updates if you are using a remote data store.

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually, so what I did was take the entire block of code from Player in lobby and just pasted it into the label of the PlayerInLobbyMenu and it hasn't crashed after switching teams several times. Looks like you were right with issues arising when passing in views to other views